# resharper suggestions background color

Tags: resharper

In resharper I get a blue curly line when for example my private property is not starting with a _. Is it possible to also give these suggestions a background color?

Comment: I thought Resharper Suggestions were green wigglies and warnings were blue. You can change the colour of these wigglies via Visual Studio Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors but only the foreground colour, not the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify which version you are running but I am running ReSharper 6.1 and, while I can set the foreground colour, the background colour of the environment seems to override the background colour setting of the wiggly line. As @Piers Myers wrote, it's accessible via Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->ReSharper Warning.